# What does weapon inertia mean?

Tags: crysis

In Crysis and Crysis Warhead there is an option called weapon inertia with a slider. What is weapon inertia and how does it influence my gameplay when I put the the slider to lowest/middle/highest position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user98085 have already pointed out, this adds simulated inertia (delay on movement) to the weapons. However this really is just an aesthetic detail, as bullets will still instantaneously fly to the center of the screen, as illustrated by this video by aucoorslt on YouTube:

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia), this setting defines how much delay and resistance there is on moving the weapon. High weapon inertia results in sluggish, slightly delayed movement, while with a low setting the movement gets closer to instantaneous.

Both have their up- and downside, some of it may be considered "realism" and some can be about precision. Largely, this is up to personal preference, but obviously a low inertia setting gives you direct control where a high setting wouldn't.

Comment: Are you sure this effect actually ads delay? I've always thought that it's only cosmetic setting.